AWS RDS Postgres inaccessible after upgrade and reboot
As the title says. I am unable to connect to and AWS RDS Postgres db after upgrade and reboot.
Context:
We run an EKS cluster with java based microservices, each service has it's own user and schema in the RDS Postgres db. After adding yet another service to the cluster we noticed that the DB ran out of connections. As a quick fix we've changed the DB instance type to give it more memory (it's a dev environment and was naively provisioned with db.t3.micro instance class). This has solved the connection issue for the services in EKS, but ever since the reboot we are no longer able to connect to the DB from outside the cluster (via DataGrip or PGAdmin).
DB is and always was publicly accessible, and the security group has two inbound rules:

one for the EKS cluster,
one for all ip traffic (0.0.0.0/0) - I know! it's dev environment and will be more secure in prod.

Let me reiterate.

No AWS config has changed.
EKS and RDS are deployed in the same VPC.
DB is set to be publicly accessible.
SG allows all ip traffic.
DB was previously accessible via DataGrip.

I tried changing the security group settings and setting it to my IP, office VPN with no changes in behaviour. Even removing the all ip rule did not change the error message:
DataGrip:
DBMS: PostgreSQL (ver. 16.2)
Case sensitivity: plain=lower, delimited=exact
Driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver (ver. 42.6.0, JDBC4.2)
The connection attempt failed.

When making the same SG changes in another DB instance (a sandbox db if you will) I saw changes in behaviour - blocking and unblocking access, if that makes sense.
Any tips on how to investigate this further?
